# lein aliases on do with nested argument throws an error

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to do an `:aliases` on lein, the [doc](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L204) says I can do something like this:

```
:aliases {["do" ["cljsbuild" "clean"] ["cljsbuild" "once"] ["cljsbuild" "auto"]]}
```

it throws an error, since map need an even argument, so I added a key:

```
:aliases {"re-cljs" ["do" ["cljsbuild" "clean"] ["cljsbuild" "once"] ["cljsbuild" "auto"]]}
```

It throws, `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: endsWith for class clojure.lang.PersistentVector`. Now I have no idea how fix this.

Comment: Works fine for me. Which version of Leinigen are you using?

Comment: Leiningen 2.2.0. Invoked it using `lein re-cljs`

Comment: Could you try using a newer version of Leiningen? I vaguely remember a bug like this in an older version.....

Comment: @sloth updated and it works, thx. If you want you can post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me, but I vaguely remember a bug like this in an older version of Leiningen.

Upgrade to a newer version (Leiningen 2.2.0 is *old*) and this problem should be gone.